# Streaming from a second computer

Tags: streaming

I play games on my laptop, and they run at about 30-45 fps, which is bearable for me. But when I try to stream, the frame rate drops to 20 or lower, which is unplayable for me.

I have a second computer though (a Mac, the laptop is Win7), and I'm wondering if there is anyway to stream the game content (onto Twitch.tv) from my laptop using my Mac.

Is this possible, and how would I go about doing it?

Comment: steam it to what exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound Twitch.tv

Comment: You need to update your question. I am not sure what exactly your asking is possible.

Comment: Do you have a reasonably recent NVIDIA GPU? If so, are you using Geforce Experience to stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing you want to look for is a *{ConnectionType} Capture Card with Passthrough* (Where `{ConnectionType}` is VGA, HDMI, DVI, etc.).

[This site](http://bestcapturecard.com/best-hdmi-capture-card-list) has a good list of HDMI capture cards that you might take a look at, including supported OS (Windows/Mac/Linux).

Whether you can stream the result directly to twitch or another streaming service is a second question that will depend on the card you select. Many cards show up as a standard video capture device, which means that if you can stream a web cam, then you stream these.

Comment: When you say 'capture card', is that a card I have to put in my computer, or can it be a standalone box? Because neither of my computers have PCI slots.

Comment: They come with USB, Firewire, Thunderbolt and whatnot. I’m sure you’ll find one that works for you. Quite the investment though: Are you sure you actually need this?

Comment: Probably not, and I doubt I'll be doing this since apparently it's pretty pricey.